# How to convert my if statement to a loop

Tags: java, android, loops

Hi can you help me convert my if statement into a loop?

```
Event ev1 = new Event(Color.RED, milliseconds, from +" to "+ to);
Event ev2 = new Event(Color.RED, milliseconds, from +" to "+ to);
Event ev3 = new Event(Color.RED, milliseconds, from +" to "+ to);
compactCalendarView.addEvent(ev1);

if(ev1.toString().contains("")){
  compactCalendarView.addEvent(ev1);
} else if (ev2.toString().contains("")){
  compactCalendarView.addEvent(ev2);
} else if(ev3.toString().contains("")){
  compactCalendarView.addEvent(ev3);
}
```

Comment: Dont get me wrong; but you really accepted the answer that misses the *real* point of your code. And beyond that: I am pretty sure that his code is **not** doing the same as your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define events as a events array and use next loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < eventsLimit; i ++)
    if(/* if accepted event */){
        compactCalendarView.addEvent(
            new Event(Color.RED, milliseconds, from +" to "+ to));
        break;
    }
```

Comment: For the record: most likely, **your** code is adding **three different** object references to that list. His code is adding the **same** reference **two** times. That is not at all the same.

Comment: @Sergey - I believe in this case it's better to try and educate OP than trying to fit a square peg into a round hole. Sure you can come up with some solution that uses a loop but the core of the problem is better adressed by GhostCat's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can reduce your code to its core:

```
Event ev = new Event(Color.RED, milliseconds, from +" to "+ to),
compactCalendarView.addEvent(ev);
compactCalendarView.addEvent(ev);
```

Because that is what your code is **really** doing! **All** the other lines in your example input do not have any effect.

The point is: you are creating **three** events that all have a non-empty message. So that first `if` will always be true. Thus **your** code does nothing else but add that *first* reference to the view 2 times.

But it wouldn't make any difference: because all three events are "equal" anyway; as you create them the very same way each time! So there is no point in checking which of those three identical events you intend to add to your view.

And beyond that: it is **super bad** practice to make decisions on the result of a `toString()` call. Don't do that.

Long story short: the *real* answer here is: please step back. And learn about the concepts you intend to use in your code. Because right now, you do not understand them.

Comment: OP propably already has left the building. A shame because this contains many gold nuggets OP better learn from ...

Comment: Maybe he comes back next week. It is 9 am in the morning; and I already reached 95 rep, so almost half of my daily goal, so whatever. But seriously: thank you very much for you support. Although I am confident in the thoughts I put down; it is always nice to have somebody looking over things and giving feedback. Just expressed my gratitude on that ... really nice question that is on TDD. I didn't do TDD before 2014 or so ;-)

Comment: Thanks. The *trying* part of that question hasn't changed one bit though ;)